# Using 'data:post.url' does not work in Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: html, facebook, blogger

I have a facebook comment plugin on my website:
It is working when I put my certain blogger post's url into the data-href

```
<div class="fb-comments" 
data-href="http://vctestsite.blogspot.com/2015/04/just-another-lorem-human-post-check-to.html" 
data-numposts="3" 
data-colorscheme="light">
</div>
```

Of course, if I use that code above in my blogger template, all of the facebook comments in all of my blogger posts will be the same.

But when I change that data-href into data:post.url, it doesnt work. The comment plugin won't come out in my blog.

```
<div class="fb-comments" 
data-href="data:post.url" 
data-numposts="3" 
data-colorscheme="light">
</div>
```

Here is the test site: http://vctestsite.blogspot.com/2015/04/just-another-lorem-human-post-check-to.html

That's just my test site. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

solved!

```
<div class="fb-comments" expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:xid='data:post.id' width='450'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

update `expr:href='data:blog.canonicalUrl'` to `data-href="data:post.url"` in your code.